# Feature table relations

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have a feature table which gets data from a feature service. That service has a relation with a table. 
Can I use that table to populate some of the columns in the feature table?

```
var myFeatureTable = new FeatureTable({
                featureLayer: featureTableLayer,
                showGridMenu: true,
                gridOptions: gridOptions,
                showRelatedRecords: true,
                syncSelection: true,
                zoomToSelection: true,
                editable: true,
                outFields: [
                    "objectid", "mesto_sifra", "ulici_cr_fk", "ime_na_ulica_opstina", "novo_ime_na_ulica", "tehnicki_broj", "tabla", "zabeleska_opstina", "greska_grafika", "globalid", "streetName"
                ],
                hiddenFields: ["objectid", "globalid"],  // field that end-user can show, but is hidden on startup
                fieldInfos: [
                    {
                        name: 'mesto_sifra',
                        alias: 'Шифра на населено место',
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'mesto_ime',
                        alias: 'Име на населено место',
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ulici_cr_fk',
                        alias: 'Име на улица',
                        editable: false
                    },
                    {
                        name: "streetName",
                        alias: 'Име на улица (општина)',
                        editable: true
                    },
```

I also have the event which enables related records.

```
myFeatureTable.on("show-related-records", function (evt) {
                console.log("show-related-records event - ", evt);
            });
```

Even so, the feature table doesn't show the column for `streetName`